# Remove port and keep the host

Tags: javascript, regex, vector-vrl

I've URL like following

```
https://www.aaaa.com:5000  -> https://www.aaaa.com
https://bbbb.com:443   -> https://bbbb.com
https://cccc.com     -> https://cccc.com
```

I need to remove only the port ..

I've tried with the following which doesn't works, it takes all the data

https://regex101.com/r/CIiALR/1

```
(https?://.*):(\d*)\/?(.*)`
```

The trick is that I must use only regex not js lib, as I need it for using Vector.

https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/

Also: https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/#parse-custom-logs

Comment: What does your regex call look like? Are you using replace?

Comment: Why did you tag this with JS if JS isn't even used?  Also: Your regex works, provided you properly escape it and remove invalid flag denotations. (Re: `//` -> `\/\/` and `\g` -> `/g`([working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qAjIiI/1)))

Comment: Could you tag the language/environment you are using? There may be something available that's not a library to help you.

Comment: @phuzi - not found any tags for it... "vector" is too generic ....

Comment: Fair enough, may be you could edit the question to state it explicitly

Comment: @phuzi They did; did you refresh yet?

Comment: @JennyM You say you only need to remove the port, but your third example removes an invalid period at the end.  If this is not what you meant, can you clarify please?

Comment: @Daedalus - sorry my typo, the period is not included

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex, you may use the `url` object for this kind of work.

```js
var url = new URL('https://www.aaaa.com:5000');
url.port = '';
console.log(url.toString());
```

More about the url object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: @JennyM The url object isn't a lib.

Comment: Why must you use regex. Many languages will have built in support for handling URLs

Comment: @phuzi https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/ you can use a named capture group and optionally match the port number:

```
^(?P<withoutport>https?://[^/\s]+?)(?::\d+|$)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<withoutport>` Named group

  - `https?://` Match the protocol
  - `[^/\s]+?` Match by any char except `/` or a whitespace char in a non greedy way
- `)` Close named group
- `(?::\d+|$)` Match `:` and 1+ digits, or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5KLlLg/1)

Or you can make it as specific as you require:

```
 ^(?P<withoutport>https?://[^/\s]+?)(?:[:?#/]\S*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QunEqi/1)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of `vector` you are using - I would suggest using the built in [parse_url](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/functions/#parse_url) function to extract out which parts you want.

Example TOML:

```
[sources.my_demo_logs_source]
type = "demo_logs"
format = "shuffle"
lines = [ "https://www.aaaa.com:5000" , "https://bbbb.com:443", "https://cccc.com" ]

[transforms.my_transform]
type = "remap"
inputs = [ "my_demo_logs_source" ]
source = """
url_parts = parse_url!(.message)
.url = join!([ url_parts.scheme, url_parts.host ],  "://")
"""

[sinks.my_sink_id]
type = "console"
inputs = [ "my_transform" ]
target = "stdout"

  [sinks.my_sink_id.encoding]
  codec = "json"
```

Example output:

```
{"message":"https://bbbb.com:443","source_type":"demo_logs","timestamp":"2022-06-28T07:20:45.202665432Z","url":"https://bbbb.com"}
{"message":"https://www.aaaa.com:5000","source_type":"demo_logs","timestamp":"2022-06-28T07:20:46.202754200Z","url":"https://www.aaaa.com"}
{"message":"https://cccc.com","source_type":"demo_logs","timestamp":"2022-06-28T07:20:47.201350600Z","url":"https://cccc.com"}
```

This was tested with:

```
❯ vector --version
vector 0.22.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 5e937e3 2022-06-01)
```